# How to combine multiple event data into one object or variable suitable for use with fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, fullcalendar

I am getting data from a DB for populating events in fullcalendar.js
I get this information prior to initiating `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({})`

If I knew how many events I was going to have I could create the calendar with the code below

```
events: [               
            eventz[0],
            eventz[1]
        ]
```

Where eventz contain information like

```
eventz[eventcounter]={  
                    className: title[counter],
                    title: title[counter],
                    start: new Date(y, m, weekday, result[hour1], result[minute1]),
                    end: new Date(y, m, weekday, result[hour2], result[minute2]),
                    allDay: false
                                };
```

EDIT: More information-events would normally contain information written like below

```
events:[
        {//event1
        title: 'TENTATIVE',
        start: new Date(y, m, monday, 0, 30),
        end: new Date(y, m, monday, 1, 0),
        allDay: false
        },
        {//event2
        title: 'TENTATIVE',
        start: new Date(y, m, monday, 0, 30),
        end: new Date(y, m, monday, 1, 0),
        allDay: false
        }
]
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how many events I'm going to get.
I thought that prior to initiating the calendar, I could combine the events into one object or variable (something like the code below-where `allevents={eventz[0]},{eventz[1]}`).

```
events: [               
            allevents
        ]
```

**QUESTIONs**

Is it possible to combine events into one object or variable like above? If yes, how? If no, I'd be interested in alternative methods for entering dynamic event data into fullcalendar. Thanks :)

**WHAT I have tried**

```
//combine all events into one
        for (var i=0;i<=counter;i++)
        {
            allevents+=eventz[i];
            if (i!=counter)
            {
                allevents+=',';
            }
        }
```

I've tried quite a few things, but this feels like I'm doing ridiculous stuff and this seems like an easy question (for people other than me).

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't pass `eventz` directly to `.fullCalendar()`? One section of your pseudo-code is merely coping one array to another while another is concatenating an array into a string. Can you give a more clear example of your sample input and the output you're after?

Comment: I had tried just using `eventz` but no events appeared on the calendar and no errors in firebug.

Comment: The only reason I wanted to combine the event data into a variable/object/thingymajig was because I thought it would make it easier to add the data to the calendar. I'd just loop through the events combining them into one variable and plug it into the events option.

Comment: I've edit the question and added more information.

Comment: Looking at the FullCalendar documentation it looks like the events attribute you instantiate the calendar with can be a function that you can use to generate event objects. This may be the solution you're looking for. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

Comment: @Colin At a glance, the problem with this method (in my case) is that I've already collected the data. I think it would solve my problem, but it would mean making an extra request. I'll keep it in mind though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used array concatenation to solve my problem.

```
//Combines all events into one
        if (eventcounter>0) //Check that there is an event!
        {
            var allevents=[eventz[0]]; 
            for (var varname=1; varname<=eventcounter; varname++)
            {               
                allevents=allevents.concat([eventz[varname]]);
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

Instead of using 'events' attribute use 'eventSources' attribute.

Before:

```
events : eventArrayFirst
```

After:

```
eventSources: [
    eventArrayFirst,
    eventArraySecond
]
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct way to do it without the need to mess about combining arrays in Javascript. The code is already written for you.

Answer (score -2):

If your final array after combining all the events in single array looks like

`var eventz = [
        {//event1
        title: 'TENTATIVE',
        start: new Date(y, m, monday, 0, 30),
        end: new Date(y, m, monday, 1, 0),
        allDay: false
        },
        {//event2
        title: 'TENTATIVE',
        start: new Date(y, m, monday, 0, 30),
        end: new Date(y, m, monday, 1, 0),
        allDay: false
        }
];`

Then this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ux2jQ/) may help you